# In asp.net C# webform Have a list view with one button after binding it convert to many buttons dynamically want to highlight Clicked button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, listview

I have Button btnTags in List View When ListView is Bind then its has Buttons Like

btnTags1 btnTags2 btnTags3 btnTags4 btnTags5 btnTags6

When Clicked on btnTags2 
the Color of btnTags2 Should Change

When Clicked on A3 
the btnTags2 color should rest to default 
and A3 should be highlighted

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewCompanyServicesList" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder" OnItemCommand="ListViewCompanyServicesList_ItemCommand">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <div id="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
    </div>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnTags" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Service") %>' CommandName="SelectService" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ServiceId") %>' CssClass="label label-default" Style="display: inline-block" OnClick="btnTags_Click" />
  </ItemTemplate>
  <EmptyDataTemplate>
    <div class="promote_contentBox2">
      <p class="well" style="font-size: 80%;">No record Found</p>
    </div>
  </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: you can do it using simple css like this a[id*='btnTags']:visited { color:#CCC; } replace #ccc with required . It says if there is any id containing btnTags ( like A1, A2 etc..), if that link is visited, then CSS will be applied.

Comment: Not working bcoz i have linkbutton and wen its clicked  due to postback it gets rest